# Symfony logged but not authenticated

Tags: php, security, symfony, authentication

Hi I am facing a problem with symfony 2.6 authentication via a logging form. I have followed the Symfony documentation to do this.

My problem is that when I attempt to log into my app that works but I'm not authenticated according to the profiler.

in my log i have found this :

> [2015-02-18 20:44:33] security.INFO: User "zouhair@speeddev.com" has
>   been authenticated successfully [] [] ... 2015-02-18 20:57:28]
>   request.INFO: Matched route "speed_dev_myprojects_homepage"
>   (parameters: "_controller":
>   "SpeedDev\MyprojectsBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction",
>   "_route": "speed_dev_myprojects_homepage") [] [] [2015-02-18 20:57:28]
>   security.DEBUG: Read SecurityContext from the session [] []
>   [2015-02-18 20:57:28] security.DEBUG: Checking secure context token:
>   UsernamePasswordToken(user="", authenticated=true, roles="ROLE_MOE")
>   [] []

I don't know why there is no _username value from

here is my loginAction :

```
    namespace SpeedDev\MyprojectsBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use SpeedDev\MyprojectsBundle\Entity\Employee;

class SecurityController extends Controller {

    public function loginAction() {

        $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);

        $helper = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

        return $this->render('SpeedDevMyprojectsBundle:Security:login.html.twig', array(
                    'last_username' => $helper->getLastUsername(),
                    'error' => $helper->getLastAuthenticationError(),
        ));
    }

}
```

here is my security.yml file :

```
firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main_login:
            pattern:   ^/login$
            anonymous: true

        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/
            remote_user:
                provider: chain_provider
            wsse:      true
            anonymous: false
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login_check

                # par défaut, le formulaire de login *doit* être un POST,
                # et pas un GET
                post_only:                      true
                remember_me:                    true

                # options de redirection lorsque le login a réussi (vous
                # pouvez en lire plus ci-dessous)
                always_use_default_target_path: false
                default_target_path:            speed_dev_myprojects_homepage
                target_path_parameter:          _target_path
                use_referer:                    false

                # options de redirection lorsque le login échoue (vous
                # pouvez en lire plus ci-dessous)
               # failure_path:                   login_failure
               # failure_forward:                false

                # noms des champs pour le nom d'utilisateur et le mot
                # de passe
                username_parameter:             _username
                password_parameter:             _password

                # options du token csrf
                csrf_parameter:                 _csrf_token
                intention:                      authenticate

                require_previous_session: true

            remember_me:                    
                    key:      "%secret%"
                    lifetime: 31536000 # 365 jours en secondes
                    path:     /
                    domain:   ~ # Prend la valeur par défaut du domaine courant depuis $_SERVER
            logout:
                    path:   logout
                    target: speed_dev_myprojects_homepage


    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_MOE }
```

Comment: you'll probably need to post your user entity for us to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Ok no problem I didn't want to overload the post I'll edit it when I get home. But I have 2 users entity : 1 entity client and 1 entity employee and i used a mulitple_user_provider.

Comment: Where is your `chain_provider` defined ?